# Why is my bread not mixing and cooking properly

Tags: bread, dough

When I add my ingredients like my bread machine manual says I'm getting this tangled ugly mass of bread. It rises some but when it mixes it breaks apart and doesn't join together again like my previous loaves. This has happened to me twice now, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We need *a lot more information* to answer this: Could you give us your recipe please and what exactly your are doing. And of course what is the difference to your previous loaves that were ok - other recipe, other machine, other preparation...?. And if you had pictures... that would be perfect! You can simply [edit](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61517/why-is-my-bread-not-mixing-and-cooking-properly) your question to fill in as much information as you can give us, thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same kind of flour as you were previously? This sounds rather like you might be using a low-gluten or gluten-free flour in a recipe intended for a high gluten flour.

Comment: I have figured out my problem, my bread flour was old and expired

Comment: Zach, it is allowed and even encouraged here to post the solution to your problem as an answer, not a comment, if you find it after writing the question.